# I live in a multi unit home and we have two heat meters but only one thermostat. What is needed to get a 2nd thermostat?

Tags: heating, thermostat

The basement and top two floors are on one bill and the first floor is on another bill. What is needed to get the first floor its own thermostat?

Comment: Heat meters like the thing decides how much you have to pay for the heat?  Do you also have two furnaces?   We'd need to know more about the setup.

Comment: What's the energy source? Gas and electricity are common, but some places have 'heat' as a utility via for example a steam supply.

Comment: What sort of HVAC system are we dealing with here? Forced air using a furnace of some sort, or hydronic air handlers for that matter? Hydronic or steam using radiators/coils in the occupied space?  Something based on electric heat, either using heat strips in ducts/air-handlers or unit heaters in the occupied space?